# Ionic 2 Time Picker - Set picker time and not value

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, datetimepicker

```
// Controller    
this._display = 'HH:mm';
this._picker = 'HH:mm';
this._control = /* Basic angular form control with value */

// View     
<ion-datetime [displayFormat]="_display" [pickerFormat]="_picker" [formControl]="_control"></ion-datetime>
```

If `this._control.value` is null, I would like the picker to display a time that is 3 hours in the future without setting `this._control.value`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have tried to follow the steps [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-ion-datetime-how-to-set-default-picker-value-without-changing-the-model/74156/4), but it does not work:

```
// Controller 
setDefaultDate() {
    this._tmpDefaultDate = moment().add(3, 'hours').format('YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }

  cancel() {
    if(!this._control.value) {
      this._tmpDefaultDate = '';
    }
  }

// View
<ion-datetime [displayFormat]="_display" [pickerFormat]="_picker" [formControl]="_control" [(ngModel)]="_tmpDefaultDate" (ionCancel)="cancel()" (tap)="setDefaultDate()"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: If I understand you are using formGroup, in this case you should not use it with ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to reset the hour when the cancel button is clicked, try this code with FormGroup.

Controller:

```
this.mainForm = formBuilder.group({
  _tmpDefaultDate: moment().add(3, 'hours').format('YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss');
});

cancel() {
    this.mainForm.patchValue({
        _tmpDefaultDate: moment().add(3, 'hours').format('YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss');
});
```

}

Page:

```
<ion-datetime [displayFormat]="_display" [pickerFormat]="_picker" formControlName="_tmpDefaultDate" (ionCancel)="cancel()"></ion-datetime>
```